# Appropriate under sink coupling

Tags: plumbing, leak, drain, sink, pvc

I recently detected a small leak coming from my bathroom sink. I started disassembling and found the pipe connecting the p-trap to the wall was only loosely fitted to the wall side of the connection.

The elbow is firmly glued into the wall's pipe. It seems like I need to glue a threaded connection between the elbow and straight pipe. These pieces are 2" PVC. I'm looking for suggestions on the simplest "correct" fix.

Thanks!

[image: under sink connection]

UPDATE:

Thank you for the comments. I wanted to leave myself a good option to do a full p-trap replacement if it ever became necessary in the future. This 45 elbow is tight up to the cabinet, which would make for a much harder future job if it needed to be replaced.

I ended up getting a 1-1/2" Oatey p-trap at HD along with a "trap adapter" to make the whole thing work.

For those interested, here is a photo showing the old vs new:

[image: Old vs New p-trap]

And lastly, here is a close up of the elbow. It does look like this had a few beads of glue or something in there.

[image: Close up of elbow]

Last but not least, the final product:

[image: Final job]

Comment: Please show us the rest of the scene. It's difficult to provide solutions with half the story. We can't see how the trap interfaces with the 2" pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would clean up that elbow a bit and then look for a 2" trap adapter to cement on to the elbow and/or a reducer fitting.  Just depends on the size of a the trap and how much of that drain you want to update.

Comment: This is basically what I was looking to do. I wasn't sure on the terminology for the trap adapter. This worked great!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get some PVC glue and glue those two pieces together. You'll have to clean them off good but don't use and abrasive paper to do it because the pipes need to have a real tight fit. When assembling the two pieces, make sure the alignment is correct so the trap can be connected to it.

Comment: Use PVC cleaner, PVC primer, and if there is any doubt about getting it fully dry, "rain tolerant" PVC glue. If you get it fully dry, regular PVC glue is fine. This is simply a bad joint - either not glued at all or VERY poorly glued. And now it's filthy because it's been getting leaked through.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  OK, get out from under the sink and enjoy new year's day...

Comment: Thanks for the tips!